# What's the timing of spring setting field environment for XmlWebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a new reader for spring framwork 4.2.0.RELEASE source code. When I step through each line of code as it runs, I enter into **org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener**.

Function **configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext** is:

```
protected void configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext wac, ServletContext sc) {
    if (ObjectUtils.identityToString(wac).equals(wac.getId())) {
        String idParam = sc.getInitParameter(CONTEXT_ID_PARAM);
        if (idParam != null) {
            wac.setId(idParam);
        }
        else {
            wac.setId(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ID_PREFIX +
                    ObjectUtils.getDisplayString(sc.getContextPath()));
        }
    }

    wac.setServletContext(sc);
    String configLocationParam = sc.getInitParameter(CONFIG_LOCATION_PARAM);
    if (configLocationParam != null) {
        wac.setConfigLocation(configLocationParam);
    }

    ConfigurableEnvironment env = wac.getEnvironment();
    if (env instanceof ConfigurableWebEnvironment) {
        ((ConfigurableWebEnvironment) env).initPropertySources(sc, null);
    }

    customizeContext(sc, wac);
    wac.refresh();
}
```

However the line **ConfigurableEnvironment env = wac.getEnvironment()** makes me confused. the function **getEnvironment** is:

```
@Override
public ConfigurableEnvironment getEnvironment() {
    if (this.environment == null) {
        this.environment = createEnvironment();
    }
    return this.environment;
}
```

When I follow this code, I find **environment!=null**, but I don't know when and how spring set the enviroment?